# How can I modify Jenkins Configuration Global Security from the JENKINS_HOME Linux folder

Tags: jenkins, rhel

In the Jenkins UI, I have `OpenID Federated Login` under configureSecurity

```
http://XXXXXX:YYYY/configureSecurity/
```

[image: OpenID Federated Login]

How can I enable the script security checkbox from the server-side (which file in JENKINS_HOME holds it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you tick/untick the checkbox, the file **/var/lib/jenkins/javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.GlobalJobDslSecurityConfiguration.xml** gets updated.

The below value gets updated to **true** when you tick the checkbox;

```
    <useScriptSecurity>true</useScriptSecurity>
```

You need to restart **jenkins** service for changes to reflect. I'm not sure about what other service needs to be restarted for changes to reflect as from the console doing a simple **save** or **apply** is suffice and we don't have to restart jenkins service